# How to make .NET 6 API automatically convert an empty string from the request body into null?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a .NET 6 API with the following DTO and controller:

```cs
public class AnimalDTO
{
    // ...
    public string? Owner { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task CreateAnimal([FromBody] AnimalDTO animal)
{
    // ...
}
```

Whenever someone makes a request with `Owner` as an empty string, I would like for it to be converted to null automatically. I would also like this to be, automatically, the case for any other `string?` body parameter.

Is there any way to do this in Asp.Net 6?

Comment: Why do you want it to be null? You could use [IsNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-6.0) or [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-6.0) to check, if it is null or empty.

Comment: Why do you even want to do this? Just let the bit of your code that uses the value deal with null or empty string.

Comment: @mamen It's a requirement passed to me by the guys running the project. Also seems to be a problem with optional, unique columns.

Comment: @DavidG having the values be automatically converted makes it more convenient, since I'm required to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom [JsonConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=net-6.0) to convert empty strings:

```cs
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace MyApp.Converters
{
    public class EmptyStringConverter : JsonConverter<string>
    {
        public override string? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            return reader.GetString();
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                writer.WriteNullValue();
                return;
            }

            writer.WriteStringValue(value);
        }
    }
}
```

To use this converter on a single property, you can annotate it like so:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(EmptyStringConverter))]
public string Owner { get; set; }
```

To use the converter globally on all properties of type `string`, you can register the converter when adding your controllers in your `Program.cs` like so:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
{
    jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new EmptyStringConverter());
});
```

If you are using Json.NET/Newtonsoft.json, you can adapt my code to work with [their specification for custom converters](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure thats what you want? You could just use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` in your validation then it wouldn't matter if its null or empty string.

---

Otherwise you could try to set the default value to null but that doesn't prevent an empty string value being sent in from the client. Also Note that the `string` type is a reference type and always nullable, you don't need to add the `?`.

```
public class AnimalDTO
{
    // ...
    public string Owner { get; set; } = null;
}
```

---

If you must set empty strings to null then unfortunately there is no "Automatic" way that I know of, however you can set them to null with reflection, this is my cleanest attempt.

```
private void SetEmptyStringsToNull(object obj)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo info in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (info.PropertyType == typeof(string) && info.GetValue(obj) as string == string.Empty)
        {
            info.SetValue(obj, null, null);
        }
    }
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task CreateAnimal([FromBody] AnimalDTO animal)
{
    SetEmptyStringsToNull(animal);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That's a horrible way to do it imo.

Comment: Isn't there a more automatic way to do this to everyone? Currently, I'm using setters, but even that feels a little too hacky.

Comment: "optional unique columns" so you are doing cleanup? Honestly the empty string comes from somewhere and you should tell frontend to send in nulls. But with that said I updated my answer with a cleanup method. Goodluck.